# p-dataTable is not binding when data is not set inside ngOnInit()

Tags: angular, primeng

I've this **dialog** where user can enter some data. That dialog is part of a larger form. When user finishes entering data in the dialog and clicks `SAVE`, the data entered becomes a row in a `p-dataTable`.

```
<p-dataTable [value]="dataItems">
</p-dataTable>
```

On `SAVE`, I push items to the `dataItems` array.

```
onSave(){
  this.dataItems.push(newItem);
  this.showMyDialog = false; //to hide the dialog.
}
```

Unfortunately, nothing is happening. The grid keeps displaying: *no row to display*.

However, when I manually add data inside `ngOnit()` then it works just fine.

```
ngOnInit() {  
  let newItem = { name: 'ABC', phone: '123' }
  this.dataItems.push(newItem);
```

}

Am I missing something?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: `newItem` does not appear to be defined within `onSave()`.  Did you mean to pass it in as a parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, but sometimes Primeng table doesn't encounter changes made in data so, in that case, try this scenario -

```
onSave(newItem){
  this.dataItems = []; // Refresh datatable data by set it yo e
  this.dataItems= [newItem];
  this.showMyDialog = false; //to hide the dialog.
}
```

Comment: Is this a line of code or a comment? :`this.dataItems= [...this.dataItems, newItem];`

Comment: In case I've already have data in the `dataItems`, I'll need to save that in temp array then, right?

Comment: no, then you can use spread operator instead, maybe that would be best

Comment: Yes. I was just testing putting the content into a temp array then assign it. Then all my items are displayed. So my understanding is that  p-dataTable doesn't work with `push`. only assignment of another array. Thanks